# c# asp.net limit textbox based on drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Ok so i have a drop down list...it has two values (Training and Project). There is another textbox that takes number of wanted to be reserved seats. I want when I select the training option, the minimum number of requested can't be less than 16. no bound for project though.

Thanks 
Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void YourDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (YourDropDownList.SelectedValue == "Training")
        {
            int numberRequested = getNumberRequested(); //implement it accordingly
            if (numberRequested < 16)
            {
                //send error message
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way this could be done with JavaScript maybe better? I dont want the user to submit then find out that something is wrong...

Comment: Have a look at the jQuery Validation plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/. It might be what you're looking for. Cheers!